# Find compatible lists in a bigger list with Python

Tags: python, list, set

Hello everyone and thank you for reading my question.

So basically I have a list of lists or sets containing values from 0 to n.

An example of a list would be for n = 4.

```
L1 = [0, 1, 3, 4]
```

And I have a bigger list that contains them. For example:

```
L = [L1, L2, L3, ..., Lm]
```

What I want to do is to create a list of all the possible compatible subsets which have no intersection between them.

For instance, if I have:

```
L1 = [0, 1, 2] and L2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

These two are said to be compatible since their intersection is null.

I already wrote this function which takes a list of such lists and check if they are **all** compatible between each other.

```
def areListsCompatible(list):
     o = set(list[0])
     for i in range(1, len(list)):
         o = o & set(list[i])
         if(bool(o)==True):
             return False
return True
```

Now my question is how to write a function that takes a list and find all the possible combinations of compatible lists, 2 lists could be compatible, 3 or even 4?

I am thinking about **recursion** but don't seem to be able to get it done correctly.

Any help? Thank you.

EDIT:

Someone asked me to put a sample input and output.

Input:

```
L = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 1], [2, 3], [6, 7]]
```

Output:

```
O = [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]], #O1
     [[0, 1], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]],    #O2
     [[0, 1], [2, 3], [6, 7]],       #O3
     ...
    ]
```

And so on ...

Comment: Can you post some copy'n'pastable sample input with the output that you expect.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for commenting. Shall I put it as a comment here or edit the main post?

Comment: Edit your main post =)

Comment: *"I have a list of lists or sets containing values from 0 to n."* But `L2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` doesn't go from 0 to n though?

Comment: @Aran-Frey yeah here n = 7, not 4. Sorry for the confusion. It could take any value between 0 and n.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Done!

Comment: @Abbas Would you want e.g. `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]` to be included? Or do all results have be as exhaustive as possible?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes this should be included. Now the second part is that each list has a score so I need to chose the subset which has the highest score. But that is easy.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I got you now. Yeah I think that not including it will yield a better score, am I right?

Comment: DP - suppose there are n lists. Ln is either in or out. The solution is solve(n-1) + maybe Ln + each of those. (maintain a set of elements as part of the state for each individual solution)

Comment: @KennyOstrom I didn't understand your comment a lot. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: DP is dynamic programming, where you build larger solutions by adding things a step at a time. Or equivalently by breaking them into smaller problems to rebuild the answer from. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming I was giving a very rough idea how I would approach it from a DP perspective.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Can you hint it for me? Like give me a small code where to start? I'd appreciate it a lot

Comment: I did. It's an advanced topic, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following recursive generator function should work. I am sure the performance can be improved.

```
def subsets(lsts):
    if not lsts:
        return
    for i, lst in enumerate(lsts):
        yield [lst]
        s = set(lst)
        pool = [x for x in lsts[i+1:] if not s.intersection(x)]
        for subs in subsets(pool):
            yield [lst] + subs

>>> L = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
>>> list(subsets(L))
[[[0, 1]], 
 [[0, 1], [2, 3]], 
 [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], 
 [[0, 1], [3, 4]], 
 [[0, 1], [4, 5]], 
 [[1, 2]], 
 [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
 [[1, 2], [4, 5]], 
 [[2, 3]], 
 [[2, 3], [4, 5]], 
 [[3, 4]], 
 [[4, 5]]]
```

If you only want fully exhaustive subset lists (that no other subset could be added to), some minor tweaks will do:

```
def subsets(lsts, make_unique=True, used=None):
    if not lsts:
        yield []
    used = set(used or [])
    if make_unique:
        lsts = sorted(map(list, set(map(tuple, lsts))))
    for i, lst in enumerate(lsts):
        s = set(lst)
        pool = [x for x in lsts if not s.intersection(x)]
        for subs in subsets(pool, make_unique=False, used=used):
            if not used.intersection(map(tuple, subs)):
                yield [lst] + subs
            used.add(tuple(lst))

>>> list(subsets(L))
[[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], 
 [[0, 1], [3, 4]], 
 [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
 [[1, 2], [4, 5]]]
>>> L = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 1], [2, 3], [6, 7]]
>>> list(subsets(L))
[[[0, 1], [2, 3], [6, 7]], 
 [[0, 1], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]], 
 [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However I have a few questions: What if I don't want to include the list alone like [0,1] and only have the bigger lists like [0,1] [2,3] and [4,5] only..

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think [0,1], [4,5] is not added?

Comment: Because one could add [2, 3] to it without violation, rendering it non-exhaustive.

Comment: If for example I have L = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 1], [2, 3], [6, 7]], your second code is giving me O = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7]] only but I would love to add [0,1],[2,3] to use it elsewhere, how to do that?

Comment: Amended the exhaustive approach again. Now you should get all of them :)